# Making nested awk fault tolerant

Tags: shell, sh

I have this command (part of a for loop) that tries to get the start time of a process in seconds and stores it into a variable for later use. The command parses `/proc/<pid>/stat`. In the context of this command a process can be ephemeral and hence by the time I actually run this command, the directory may no longer exist. This causes the nested awk to fail and cause a syntax error in the outer division command. How can I prevent this?

```
starttime=$(($(awk '{print $22}' $d/stat) / systick));
```

`$d` is `/proc/<pid>`

Comment: Check for presence of `$d/stat` before executing `awk`

Comment: @anubhava what did you actually edit? Also checking for presence won't work. it can pass the check and still fail.

Comment: If the stat special file doesn't exist, what is the result you wish to obtain from the division?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma So the variable assignment is part of a for loop, can I get it to continue if the nested awk fails? IF thats not possible because of the outer division, maybe mark the result as 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this:

```
starttime=$(($(awk '{print $22}' $d/stat 2>/dev/null || echo 0) / systick));
```

Basically if `awk` fails for some reason, such as the special PID stat file not being there anymore, then it returns 0 to the division.

This way you require little change to your code.

PS: I am assuming that systick will always be something else other than 0.

Comment: yep, no divide by zero errors because of that. Let me try it out and get back :)